# TABLEAU - select top 3 based on the values in row

Tags: tableau-api, rank, rolling-computation

Sorry for this possibly easy question but I am a newbie to Tableau.
Suppose you have a following dataset:

```
CLASS,VALUE
    A,3
    A,5
    B,10
    A,9
```

I want Tableau to have a set/calculated field (which one?) with a formula saying that I want highest 3 values from the dataset **provided they belong to class A.** Is it possible in a formula in Tableau?

Comment: Do you want top 3 from every class or top 3 from class A only?

Comment: In the solution i have proposed, you can filter it for A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not want to aggregate `VALUE` measure.  Thus proceed as follows-

Convert `Value` to dimension

Add both class and value to view.  Check that value has not been aggregated to.

Add new calculated field with value just `1` into it.  Add this field to view.  Add table calculation to it and sort it according to `value` descending.

Filter both rank and class.  You'll get top 'n' values of desired class (filtered).

See sample data used

[image]

table calculation

[image]

output

[image]

Comment: The nice part of this approach is that it easily expands to multiple classes. Table calcs are very flexible. The downside is that the data has to be fetched to perform the table calc on the client side, (even if most of the data is not displayed) So using a table calc to find the top N when you have very large data sets can be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Making a set is pretty easy -- then you'll have to learn how to use the set to accomplish your goals.

Working exclusively in the data pane on the left margin sidebar

1. Duplicate the Value field. Drag the duplicate field to the dimension section to make it dimension. Make sure it is discrete (blue).
2. Edit the duplicated Value field. Rename it A-Value and revise the calculation definition to be `if [Class] = "A" then [Value] end`. The field [A-Value] now returns the [Value] for records with class A, and has no value (i.e. null) otherwise.
3. Create a set based on the A-Value field (right click). Name it Top-A-Values. In the set dialog box, define the set by going to the Top tab, selecting Top by Formula,  choosing 3 as the number of members, and entering the following formula `[A-Value]` -- that is just the name of your field

The set now contains the top 3 A-Values. You can, for instance, put the set on the row shelf and click on it to choose show all members.

There are many different ways to define and use sets for different purposes. This just scratches the surface.

Comment: Yes, Alex I agree that this approach may be faster given the situation that user may not have to expand top values to other classes.  Very good approach indeed. Thanks